# How to make Robot mouse actions working with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I'm using Selenium 3.14.0. I am using jawa Robot library to simulate mousWheel and mouseMove actions. Unfortunately they are not working and no exception is thrown either. I dont; know what i am doing wrong: Below is my code:

```
    Point browserPosition = driver.manage().window().getPosition();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    long offsetX = (long) js.executeScript("return (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth)");
    long offsetY = (long) js.executeScript("return (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)");

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(50);

    robot.mouseMove((int) (browserPosition.getX() + offsetX + 10), (int) (browserPosition.getY() + offsetY + 10));

    robot.setAutoDelay(50); 
    robot.mouseWheel(200);
```

I have to move mouse to my browser area and then need to scale image via mouse wheel action.

Comment: print these (int) (browserPosition.getX() + offsetX + 10), (int) (browserPosition.getY() + offsetY + 10) and see the values, are they larger enough to move on to page. mouse move generally work and you can see mouse icon

Comment: Already done that. Mouse pointer stays at the same location. It does not move at all.

Comment: simply try giving  robot.mouseMove(250,250) and see once

Comment: No luck at all :(

Comment: i tried this simple one import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassB {

 
 
 @Test
 public void testa() throws AWTException {
  
  Robot r=new Robot();
  r.mouseMove(450, 450);
 }
 
 
 
} which works fine, looks there is no issue with robot, something else

Comment: not working on my mac.

Comment: see this https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton/issues/19

Comment: can u suggest any other way to achieve this usecase?